# Cypher Neptune Query to graph representation in react

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-neptune

I want to create a exact graph representation in ReactJS as same as AWS Neptune provide. Can anyone help me to create or suggest some libraries.

I have tried highcharts libraries and chartjs, but not getting the expected result

Comment: Is the question about how to build a visualization of the graph?

Comment: yes @KelvinLawrence

Answer (score 0):

As you mention [Amazon Neptune](https://aws.amazon.com/neptune/), I am going to assume you are referring to the [Graph Notebook](https://github.com/aws/graph-notebook) and [Graph Explorer](https://github.com/aws/graph-explorer) open source projects.

There are many open source and commercially available Javascript graph/network rendering libraries available these days. The Graph Notebook project uses [Vis.js networks](https://github.com/visjs/vis-network). Graph Explorer currently uses [Cytoscape](https://cytoscape.org/).

Perhaps take a look at those libraries, and as I mentioned there are many more choices than just these two. You may also find it beneficial to look at the source code for graph-explorer and graph-notebook using the links I added above.

It's actually quite simple to build some attractive graph visualizations with tools such as these.